# PHP Regex error

Tags: php, regex

I am new to PHP regex. I've written below code, but there is something wrong. Could someone please suggest to me what is going wrong?

[**Code Link**](https://ideone.com/lIzd8X)

**Input:**

```
    1 => 'String',
    2 => 'String String',
    3 => 'email',
    4 => 'date',
    5 => 'date',
    6 => 'String String',
    7 => 'String String',
    8 => 'String',
    9 => 'date'
```

**Here is the same code from above link:**

```
<?php 
    $text = "john123 john william johnw@hotmail.com 2015-05-09 13:21:41 2015-08-07 13:21:41 James James William William group1 2015-05-30 18:05:39"; 

    $regex = '~([a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+) ([-\w.+]+@[-\w.+]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}) (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) ([a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z]+) (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})~i';

    if ( preg_match( $regex, $text ) ) {
         echo $text . " is a valid text. We can accept it.";
    } else { 
         echo $text . " is an invalid text. Please try again.";
    } 

?>
```

Comment: Some "strings" contain digits too. You should use anchors in your pattern.

Comment: What if its invalid? Does `Please try again` mean somebody has to retype the whole line in again? This is usually a generated string ..

Comment: Maybe a split on whitespace, then validate the fields separately. This way you're not constrained by field characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your test string `john123` and `group1` has digits which you are trying to match with `[a-zA-Z]+` make them `[a-zA-Z\d]+` and also other groups where digits are possible.. Use the following:

```
([a-zA-Z\d]+) ([a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+) ([-\w.+]+@[-\w.+]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}) (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) ([a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z\d]+) (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})
```

**Edit:** Since you are already using `i` (case insentitive) modifier.. you can just have `[a-z]+` for alphabet and `[a-z\d]+` for alphanumeric characters.

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cD2rD8/1)

Comment: Also might be worth mentioning the `i` modifier if the case isn't important. Can avoid the `a-zA-Z`.

Comment: @chris85 .. yeahh missed it.. thanks for helping me improve the answer :)

Comment: @karthikmanchala i just tried your regex code, still not getting required output, here: https://ideone.com/jZSDDl